# Title of section with dollar signs

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

In tex documents of mathematics, sometimes title of section involves some math symbols, such as

```
\section{Groups with $G'=Z(G)$}
```

However, using dollar sign in title of section always shows some warning.

What should be the way to write title of sections involving math symbols?

Comment: Maybe you should set another title for toc or make a difference for hyperlinks. Do you use `hyperref`?

Comment: Dear TeXnician, I use the hyperref package. Still a problem arises, not of running file, but it shows warning. (I used command      "\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red, citecolor=red]{hyperref}")

Comment: Have a look at the suggested link. If it something completely different, then please post a MWE (minimal code example showing your problem).

Comment: Instead of short command " \usepackage{hyperref}", I had written a long command for it as in above comment. The long command shows warning, but this short command doesn't show; I don't know why this happens.